# TSNE with CSV file

Tags: java, visualization, word2vec

I am currently working on **t-SNE** Visualization with **Word2vec**. I currently have a CSV file with this format "`2915.865634943799,3746.346408279378,king`" (And of course many more data).

Is there a way to do a **t-SNE** visualization scattered graph to plot this (with king being the label)?

Comment: Any language specification?

Comment: Preferrably in Java. Thanks!